# How to use an Arduino Uno + Keyboard Firmware to make a "N Key Rollover" Game Pad

Tags: arduino-uno, usb

Hello I have flashed my Arduino Uno with USB keyboard firmware from this tutorial http://mitchtech.net/arduino-usb-hid-keyboard/#comment-6786, and I have been successful sending individual key presses but, not when trying to press an hold a key. I am attempting to use this firmware to create a custom Game Pad to USB adapter, the only issue is sending simultaneous keystrokes (not sending them one at a time). If you know how to accomplish this task I would be very happy. The technical term for this is "Key Rollover"

Comment: Howmany buttons are you checking and to which pins do you have them connected?

Comment: My game pad has 12 buttons, and they are connected with shift registers so only 3 pins. Checking the button states isn't the issue. I am trying to use the game pad as a keyboard with the Keyboard firmware from the tutorial above but, to play games I need to be able to press many keys simultaneously.

Comment: The easiest option would be to switch to an Arduino that has a USB-capable main MCU, such as the Leonardo.

Comment: I understand why this would be a good way to do this since the people from arduino provide a keyboard library for the Leonardo but, with my arduino uno I have already got to be plug n' play as a keyboard. The problem is getting more than one button press at a time. I need to add simultaneous key presses "Key Rollover"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closer research on this topic I have found the answer to my problem but,thank you to all that have tried to help. In order to do "Key Rollover" I needed to write the additional key states to the remaining values of the buffer array then write the values with Serial.write(buf,8). I can now use my Arduino Uno + My Game Pads as controllers for all my computer games.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to send random keys do you?

Well consider using the code below as your base.
It's using [Port Manipulation](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) to read the buttons (Digital 0 to 7).

```
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);//Start serial connection.
  DDRD = 0b00000000; //Set Data Direction Register of port D to inputs (attach keys to digital pins 0to7;
  delay(200); //Misc delay.
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.write(PIND, 8);    // Send states of PORTD (digital 0 to 7)
}
```

I strongly suggest you use pull-down/up resistors on the buttons also.
Adjust your code to the amount of keys you're using, or pull the pins low if not used. To avoid receiving random/floating pin values.

Comment: The problem is not with the '328P itself but with the communications channel with the USB chip.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, I skipped a bit too fast through the article. The new answer should fit the needs of the 'asker'.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am having issues with. I have all ready have the game pad and have been able to read the input values from the controller. When I press one button sending the keystroke is easy. It is when I need to have many key presses as held keys. Other wise the game will think I am repeatedly pressing different buttons.

Comment: Than you should only send the state of your key when it's changed?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post an example of your updated code?  I'm working on a similar project but a complete n00b as far as using the Arduino goes.